# Are relocation expenses tax deductible in Germany for an Italy-Germany transfer (for job purposes)?

Tags: germany, relocation, tax-deductions

I am an Italian citizen, currently living there, and I will relocate to Germany because of a job that requires relocation.

I was wondering if the relocation expenses are tax deductible--and to which extent.

Some websites mention that the deduction is for any case including abroad-to-Germany, while other websites mention that this is possible only for Germany-to-Germany or Germany-abroad relocations. So, I am confused.

Comment: Save all your receipts and include the expenses, properly documented, in your first tax return as "Werbungskosten". State that they were related to a relocation for work reasons. After that, it's up to the tax office to decide if they will refund you any taxes based on these expenses – the worst that can happen is that they say no.

Answer (score 2):

With this type of expenses it is always worth trying, so do as user149408 says in their comment and

> Save all your receipts and include the expenses, properly documented, in your first tax return as "Werbungskosten". State that they were related to a relocation for work reasons. After that, it's up to the tax office to decide if they will refund you any taxes based on these expenses – the worst that can happen is that they say no.